# How to create a table WITHOUT alternating row colors when using Blueprint CSS framework?

Tags: css, colors, row, css-tables, blueprint-css

The Blueprint CSS framework makes all table rows of alternating colors by default. How to disable this behaviour for one table?

I tried to use Chrome Developer Tools to see all the styles Chrome uses for a defined table, but did not find the style which would set the colors for rows. I also searched the Internet and did not find a solution. It's like magic...

Anyone can help me out?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You need a more specific selector to override... BP is pretty general though so that shouldnt be an issue for example:

```
table.no-zebra tbody tr:nth-child(even) td,
table.no-zebra tbody tr.even td {
  background: transparent;
}
```

you can replace transparent with whatever color to make all rows a solid color.

Comment: Thanks! This answers my question accurately - to disable the styling for one specific table.

Answer (score 3):

I would just do override in my own css file

tbody tr:nth-child(even) td, tbody tr.even td {background:none;}

Answer (score 1):

This is what I put into the top of my CSS file to disable Blueprint's even table rows background color.

```
table tr:nth-child(even) td {
  background: transparent;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Possibly search for and remove (From screen.css)

```
tbody tr:nth-child(even) td, tbody tr.even td {background:#e5ecf9;}
```

Comment: That would turn off striping of all tables not just one or one's of a particular class.

Comment: Don't change blueprint, just override it. It's a bad idea to change the library -- if you load a new version of the library, you won't remember which one you removed, etc. If you override the CSS rules, when you get a new copy of the library, your overrides still function. If you want to generically remove the zebra strips from all tables, you can override the rule by adding a class or ID to your <body> tag, and create a rule for table under that class or ID.