# Firefox alternate row coloring

Tags: html, css, firefox

Designing a simple HTML table that I am going to implement alternate-row coloring on... but before I even start to do this, it appears that FF4 has applied alternate-row coloring automatically to the plain HTML table. Even after specifying my own alternate row colors that are shown properly in IE, Chrome, etc, FF still shows it's own chosen color for the alternate rows (odd numbered rows), which is a light blue color.

I've searched all over, but can't find anything related to this issue - anyone have a solution? Some FF-specific CSS I need to include to 'force' it to show my alternate color scheme?

Here is the table markup:

```
<table id="myTable">
  <tr><td>Bill</td><td>Smith</td></tr>
  <tr class="rowAlternate"><td>Joe</td><td>Blow</td></tr>
</table>
```

Here is the CSS I am using:

```
#myTable {margin: 0;}
#myTable tr {background-color: white;}
#myTable tr.rowAlternate {background-color: #EEE;}
```

Comment: Please post a sample of your table markup

Comment: This shouldn't happen. Can you show a live example?

Comment: Have you loaded the page in FF safemode?  I have a similar project running now with no issues whatsoever.  I bet you have some plugin mucking it up.

Comment: This can happen if you have decided to implement your own styling for any page that you visit.  FF supports this type of behavior.

Comment: If you have Firebug installed it will show you where the row is getting its styles from.

Comment: Firebug did it... zebra-style row-coloring coming from Blueprint CSS that for some reason was ONLY being picked up by FF. Overriding the correct CSS tags did it: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4512731/how-to-create-a-table-without-alternating-row-colors-when-using-blueprint-css-fra

Answer (score 1, accepted):

FYI, solution is here: [How to create a table WITHOUT alternating row colors when using Blueprint CSS framework?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4512731/how-to-create-a-table-without-alternating-row-colors-when-using-blueprint-css-fra)

Not sure if I should delete this question or not.

Comment: I had a feeling it was Blueprint, they have some pretty gross default table styles.

Comment: Any info on what this had to do specifically with Firefox?

Comment: I'd say leave the question. It's an interesting corner case/gotcha that might be helpful to others facing a similar issue.

Comment: @Wesley, I believe it was literally the age/versions of the browsers. IE 8, older Chrome didn't seem to follow the CSS lead, while my updated yesterday version of FF did.